# Statistically compare curves with python

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, curve

I am coming from the biomedical research field.

An experiment of mine could generate curves like in the image attached (the image attached are randomly generated example data).

I want to statistically say, that the blue curve is significantly behaving different compared to the orange one.

For example, between time ~1 - 5, the standard deviations do not overlap between the two curves, so I would assume they are statistically different.

Does anyone know what kind of statistical approach (is it an ANOVA?) I could use here to code in python?

Thanks all[image: example curve]

Comment: I suggest asking your stats question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Joe, 
Thanks so much! I didnt know this website, I am not very deep into statistics as you can see. Very nice thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**One thing I come up with in you case (having data points as time series), is to use a correlation metric (low score means low relation between your features:**
In you case you have actually 3 features (time, red_trend, blue_trend) and of course trends as average points.

**The important question here is, what correlation metric to use?**
Base on [this website, by Jason Brownlee PhD](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data/), because your features are all numeric and non-linear relation may exist you better use spearman correlation coefficient. But it never hurts to use pearson as well.

You can also see when to use other approaches (i.e. ANOVA) in the website previously motioned.

**As an example for implementation**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


t = np.linspace(1, 20, 100)
x = np.sin(np.exp(t))
y = np.cos(np.exp(t))

plt.plot(t, x)
plt.plot(t, y)

res1 = stats.spearmanr(x, y)
print(res1)
# SpearmanrResult(correlation=-0.01120912091209121, pvalue=0.9118658174696723)

res2 = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
print(res2)
# (-0.016667117318862758, 0.8692689697764168)
```

As long as your correlation is close to zero that should be no relation between your features.

**In your own test please attention to the p-value as well,** in my example the p-value is high, that is statistically insignificant (due to generating data manually), your results would be statistically significant if you manage to get p-value < 0.05.

Comment: Thank you!! I will read through that, looks very helpful.